# TensorFlow.js scatterplot showing predicted vs actual maintenance very far apart and I can't figure out why

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to figure out why the predicted maintenance and actual maintenance values are so far apart on the final scatter plot in this code.

To be very specific, I'm using tf.js@2.0.0 and tfjs-vis@1.0.2 and unfortunately using these somewhat older package versions is a necessary evil. Aside from not being able to color code visualizations with tfjs-vis 1.0.2, I don't think the versions have anything to do with the final result.

HTML:

`````
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>TensorFlow.js Machine Maintenance Project</title>

        <!-- Core TensorFlow.js library -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0"></script>

        <!-- TensorFlow.js Vis library for visualization -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-vis@1.0.2"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="evaluate"></div>
        <div id="model-performance"></div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>````

JS:
`````

```
// DATA
const sensorData = [
    { Date: '2021-01-01', Temperature: 70, Vibration: 0.3, Pressure: 15, OperationalHours: 100, MaintenanceRequired: 0 },
    { Date: '2021-01-02', Temperature: 71, Vibration: 0.31, Pressure: 16, OperationalHours: 120, MaintenanceRequired: 0 },
    { Date: '2021-01-03', Temperature: 69, Vibration: 0.29, Pressure: 15, OperationalHours: 130, MaintenanceRequired: 0 },
    { Date: '2021-01-04', Temperature: 72, Vibration: 0.35, Pressure: 17, OperationalHours: 140, MaintenanceRequired: 0 },
    { Date: '2021-01-05', Temperature: 73, Vibration: 0.4, Pressure: 18, OperationalHours: 150, MaintenanceRequired: 1 },
    { Date: '2021-01-06', Temperature: 74, Vibration: 0.33, Pressure: 17, OperationalHours: 160, MaintenanceRequired: 0 },
    { Date: '2021-01-07', Temperature: 75, Vibration: 0.34, Pressure: 18, OperationalHours: 170, MaintenanceRequired: 1 },
    { Date: '2021-01-08', Temperature: 76, Vibration: 0.36, Pressure: 19, OperationalHours: 180, MaintenanceRequired: 1 },
    { Date: '2021-01-09', Temperature: 74, Vibration: 0.32, Pressure: 17, OperationalHours: 190, MaintenanceRequired: 0 },
    { Date: '2021-01-10', Temperature: 72, Vibration: 0.31, Pressure: 16, OperationalHours: 200, MaintenanceRequired: 0 },
    { Date: '2021-01-11', Temperature: 70, Vibration: 0.3, Pressure: 15, OperationalHours: 210, MaintenanceRequired: 0 },
    { Date: '2021-01-12', Temperature: 69, Vibration: 0.28, Pressure: 14, OperationalHours: 220, MaintenanceRequired: 0 },
    { Date: '2021-01-13', Temperature: 71, Vibration: 0.35, Pressure: 16, OperationalHours: 230, MaintenanceRequired: 0 },
    { Date: '2021-01-14', Temperature: 73, Vibration: 0.37, Pressure: 17, OperationalHours: 240, MaintenanceRequired: 1 },
    { Date: '2021-01-15', Temperature: 74, Vibration: 0.39, Pressure: 18, OperationalHours: 250, MaintenanceRequired: 1 },
    { Date: '2021-01-16', Temperature: 73, Vibration: 0.4, Pressure: 18, OperationalHours: 150, MaintenanceRequired: 1 },
    { Date: '2021-01-17', Temperature: 75, Vibration: 0.34, Pressure: 18, OperationalHours: 170, MaintenanceRequired: 1 },
    { Date: '2021-01-18', Temperature: 76, Vibration: 0.36, Pressure: 19, OperationalHours: 180, MaintenanceRequired: 1 },
    { Date: '2021-01-19', Temperature: 73, Vibration: 0.37, Pressure: 17, OperationalHours: 240, MaintenanceRequired: 1 },
    { Date: '2021-01-20', Temperature: 74, Vibration: 0.39, Pressure: 18, OperationalHours: 250, MaintenanceRequired: 1 }
];

const features = sensorData.map(item => [item.Temperature, item.Vibration, item.Pressure, item.OperationalHours]);
const labels = sensorData.map(item => item.MaintenanceRequired);

const featureTensors = tf.tensor2d(features);
const labelTensors = tf.tensor1d(labels);

// Extracting individual feature values into separate arrays
const temperatures = sensorData.map(item => item.Temperature);
const vibrations = sensorData.map(item => item.Vibration);
const pressures = sensorData.map(item => item.Pressure);
const operationalHours = sensorData.map(item => item.OperationalHours);

// Finding min and max for each feature
const minTemperature = Math.min(...temperatures);
const maxTemperature = Math.max(...temperatures);

const minVibration = Math.min(...vibrations);
const maxVibration = Math.max(...vibrations);

const minPressure = Math.min(...pressures);
const maxPressure = Math.max(...pressures);

const minOperationalHours = Math.min(...operationalHours);
const maxOperationalHours = Math.max(...operationalHours);

function normalize(value, min, max) {
    return (value - min) / (max - min);
}

const normalizedData = sensorData.map(({ Temperature, Vibration, Pressure, OperationalHours, MaintenanceRequired }) => {
    return {
        Temperature: normalize(Temperature, minTemperature, maxTemperature),
        Vibration: normalize(Vibration, minVibration, maxVibration),
        Pressure: normalize(Pressure, minPressure, maxPressure),
        OperationalHours: normalize(OperationalHours, minOperationalHours, maxOperationalHours),
        MaintenanceRequired // Data already a 0 or 1 no need for nomalization
    };
});

// Example: Plotting Temperature vs Vibration
tfvis.render.scatterplot(
    { name: 'Temperature vs Vibration' },
    { values: normalizedData.map(d => ({ x: d.Temperature, y: d.Vibration })), series: ['Maintenance Required'] },
    { xLabel: 'Temperature', yLabel: 'Vibration' }
);

// Separate the data into two series with color property
const maintenanceData = normalizedData.filter(d => d.MaintenanceRequired).map(d => ({
    x: d.Pressure,
    y: d.OperationalHours
}));
const noMaintenanceData = normalizedData.filter(d => !d.MaintenanceRequired).map(d => ({
    x: d.Pressure,
    y: d.OperationalHours
}));

// Configuration for the scatter plot
const options = {
    xLabel: 'Pressure',
    yLabel: 'OperationalHours',
    // This option will zoom the plot to fit the data points

    seriesColors: ['red', 'blue'] // This color coding will not work with tfvis 1.0.2 - this option isn't available until version 1.3.0
};


const series = ['No Maintenance', 'Maintenance Required'];
const data = { values: [noMaintenanceData, maintenanceData], series }

const surface = { name: 'Pressure vs OperationalHours (Maintenance)' };
tfvis.render.scatterplot(surface, data, options);

for (let i = 1; i < normalizedData.length; i++) {
    normalizedData[i].VibrationChange = normalizedData[i].Vibration - normalizedData[i - 1].Vibration;
}

const calculateRollingAverage = (data, window) => {
    let rollingSum = 0;
    return data.map((value, index) => {
        rollingSum += value;
        if (index >= window) {
            rollingSum -= data[index - window];
            return rollingSum / window;
        } else {
            return null; // Not enough data yet for rolling average
        }
    });
};

const rollingAvgTemperature = calculateRollingAverage(sensorData.map(d => d.Temperature), 3);
const numFeatures = 4; // Temperature, Vibration, Pressure, OperationalHours
const model2 = tf.sequential();
model2.add(tf.layers.dense({ inputShape: [numFeatures], units: 10, activation: 'relu' }));
model2.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, activation: 'sigmoid' }));

function splitDataset(data, trainFraction) {
    const trainSize = Math.floor(data.length * trainFraction);

    // Shuffle array (optional, but usually a good idea)
    for (let i = data.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [data[i], data[j]] = [data[j], data[i]];
    }

    const trainData = data.slice(0, trainSize);
    const testData = data.slice(trainSize);
    return [trainData, testData];
}

const [trainData, testData] = splitDataset(normalizedData, 0.8);

model2.compile({
    optimizer: 'adam',
    loss: 'binaryCrossentropy',
    metrics: ['accuracy']
});

const features2 = sensorData.map(item => [item.Temperature, item.Vibration, item.Pressure, item.OperationalHours]);
const labels2 = sensorData.map(item => item.MaintenanceRequired);

const featureTensors2 = tf.tensor2d(features2);
const labelTensors2 = tf.tensor1d(labels2);

// Render histogram for the Temperature feature
tfvis.render.histogram(
    { name: 'Temperature Distribution' },
    featureTensors2.slice([0, 0], [-1, 1]).dataSync(), // Slices the first feature column (Temperature)
    { xAxisDomain: [minTemperature, maxTemperature] }
);

// Render histogram for the Vibration feature
tfvis.render.histogram(
    { name: 'Vibration Distribution' },
    featureTensors2.slice([0, 1], [-1, 1]).dataSync(), // Slices the second feature column (Vibration)
    { xAxisDomain: [minVibration, maxVibration] }
);

// Render histogram for the Pressure feature
tfvis.render.histogram(
    { name: 'Pressure Distribution' },
    featureTensors2.slice([0, 2], [-1, 1]).dataSync(), // Slices the third feature column (Pressure)
    { xAxisDomain: [minPressure, maxPressure] }
);

// Render histogram for the Operational Hours feature
tfvis.render.histogram(
    { name: 'Operational Hours Distribution' },
    featureTensors2.slice([0, 3], [-1, 1]).dataSync(), // Slices the fourth feature column (Operational Hours)
    { xAxisDomain: [minOperationalHours, maxOperationalHours] }
);

const model3 = tf.sequential();
model3.add(tf.layers.dense({ inputShape: [numFeatures], units: 64, activation: 'relu' }));
model3.add(tf.layers.batchNormalization());
model3.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, activation: 'sigmoid' }));



const optimizer = tf.train.sgd(0.09);
model3.compile({ optimizer: optimizer, loss: 'binaryCrossentropy', metrics: ['accuracy'] });


async function trainAndVisualizeModel(model, featureTensors, labelTensors) {
    // Create a container for evaluation metrics visualization if it doesn't exist
    let container = document.getElementById('evaluate');
    if (!container) {
        container = document.createElement('div');
        container.id = 'evaluate';
        document.body.appendChild(container);
    }

    // Train the model and visualize training metrics
    const history = await model.fit(featureTensors, labelTensors,
        {
            epochs: 100,
            callbacks: tfvis.show.fitCallbacks(container, ['loss', 'acc'])
        });
    tfvis.show.history(document.getElementById('model-performance'), history, ['loss', 'acc']);

    // Generate predictions after the model is trained
    const predictions = model.predict(featureTensors);
    const predictedLabels = predictions.dataSync();

    // Visualize the predictions vs. actual labels
    tfvis.render.scatterplot(
        { name: 'Predictions vs. Actual Labels' },
        {
            values: featureTensors.arraySync().map((row, i) => ({
                x: predictedLabels[i], y: labelTensors.arraySync()[i]
            })),
            series: ['Predicted vs Actual Maintenance']
        },
        { xLabel: 'Predicted Maintenance', yLabel: 'Actual Maintenance' }
    );
}

// Call the function to train the model and visualize results
trainAndVisualizeModel(model3, featureTensors2, labelTensors2)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Model training and visualization complete.');
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error during model training or visualization:', error);
    });
```

```
I've tried a bunch of things, from balancing the dataset (same number of 0s and 1s for the maintenanceRequired field in the data), trying different activations optimizers and loss strategies, more and less epochs... maybe it's the layers, idk. I'd appreciate any insight.

I'm expecting the predicted and actual maintenance datapoints on the final scatterplot to be at least somewhat close.
```